# Is it possible to submit a form to a remote script with ajax?

Tags: ajax, form-submit

i have have a form in site A and want to submit the form to a script located in site B.

If i submit the form normally all works well. If i try something like the following all hell breaks loose (well actually, nothing really happens :D)

`$('#gs_vote_button').click(function(){`

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://www.siteB.com/process_form.php?param1=x;param2=y',
        data: $("#gs_vote_form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#submit_error').html(data);              
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So, is it possible to submit a form to a script in a remote site, with ajax? I really need this, please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot use AJAX to send a request to a different domain.

Instead, you can make submit normal `<form>` that targets an `<iframe>`.  (Note that you would not be able to read the response)

Alternatively, if you have control over or cooperation with the remote site, you can use JSONP.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer. I do own the remote site. Could you please elaborate a bit on the iframe solution? About jsonp, i thought this is only to get data from a remote script, have no idea how to submit data to remote script, any advice?

Comment: If you own the remote site, you should use JSONP.

Comment: The `<iframe>` solution involves making a small or hidden `<iframe>`, setting the `<form>`'s target to the iframe, and submitting the form.

Comment: Hello, could you provide a simple example on how to use jsonp to actually provide data to a php script and not retrieve? Maybe i should change the type to jsonp in the above example and provide all the data in the url to call?

Comment: My problem is not how to retrieve the results of the submission but how to send the data of the form to the remote script...

Comment: You can use the same code you're using right now; just change `POST` to `GET` and add `dataType:'jsonp'`.